# How to get MongoID as string using Mongo query

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB and i know how to get MongoID as a string from PHP. But i want to know if there is any way there to get MongoID as a string using Mongo query.

My query:

```
 $result_cover_img =$db_cover_img->find(array('active_status' =>0), 
                                        array('_id','cover_img','cover_image_description'));
```

How to get MongoID as a string using query?

Comment: You don't really. You use the method from the PHP driver once data is retrieved. Chances are if you think you want this as a string then your intended purpose is wrong anyway. Why do you think you want the data as a string, when it's a perfectly good `ObjectId`?

Comment: Actually i need that as a string for API to Android Developers

Comment: If you mean as a JSON response, then it should simply stringify correctly without your intervention with any common library. You don't ask the database to return this as a "string". And outside of `mapReduce` (which you do not want here ) it will not do it.

Comment: you can parse `ObjectId` to `string` like this -  `$stringId = (string) $ObjectId;` in php..